# Showing that $f\in C'(\mathbb{R^2},\mathbb{R})$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $$f(x,y)=xy\int_{x^2-y^2}^{x^2+y^2}e^{\cos(xyt)}dt.$$
Prove that $f\in C'(\mathbb{R^2},\mathbb{R})$.

I'm not exactly sure how to approach this problem. Here's what I've tried:

First I substituted $u=xyt$ and $du =xy\,dt \iff dt=\frac{1}{xy}du$ to get

$$f(x,y)=\int_{xy(x^2-y^2)}^{xy(x^2+y^2)}e^{\cos(u)}du.$$

And by the fundamental theorem of calculus, this is just $F(xy(x^2+y^2))-F(xy(x^2-y^2))$ for some function $F\in C'(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, right? So then $f\in C'(\mathbb{R^2},\mathbb{R})$?

What am I missing? Thanks for any type of hint!

Comment: It looks perfectly OK to me.

Comment: Can you tell me what is $C'$ ?

Comment: $C'(\mathbb{R^2},\mathbb{R})$ is the set of continuously differentiable real valued functions with the domain $\mathbb{R^2}$.